# PHP: Error wit Group id

Tags: php, mysql

I am using inner join query to get info in qualifcation column, I used checkbox to insert the information and created 2 tables and join them with inner join. Now I am unable to get the data with same ID or user id in one row. Any solution?

my code is

```
 <?php include 'db.php';?>


<?php //$query = mysql_query("select * from student_info");
$query =mysql_query("SELECT s.id,s.firstname, s.lastname, s.class, s.age, s.phone,c.qualification, s.address, s.fathername
FROM student_info as s
INNER JOIN checkbox as c
ON s.id=c.userid GROUP BY s.id");

?>
```

output:

i want same id content in one row i used:
this query also:

but get this output:
 [image: Output]

[image]
please help

Comment: which one image output you want first yaa second

Comment: <?php include 'db.php';?> is this your code?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: TRY -
SELECT s.id,s.firstname, s.lastname, s.class, s.age, s.phone,min(c.userid),c.qualification, s.address, s.fathername
FROM student_info as s
INNER JOIN checkbox as c
ON s.id=c.userid GROUP BY s.id

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated in PHP &, try using `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: is there id is auto_increment ? or if you  inserting manually means .you entered same id for some users so that if you use group by it will give only one row for each id .

Answer (score 1):

You don't use aggregation' function and seems you don't want a distinct result so don't use group by

```
SELECT s.id,s.firstname, s.lastname, s.class, s.age, s.phone,
  c.qualification,    s.address, s.fathername
FROM student_info as s
INNER JOIN checkbox as c
ON s.id=c.userid
```